# What is the right way (nested functions or...)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Are both my examples the same in terms of functionality considering the fact that in error handeling I'm terminating by res.json(400, err)? Also I would like to know that in my second example the second async.each always run after the first async.each, so using results1 in the second async.each is safe? Sorry I'm new to Node and async!

**Example1:** where I'm using the results of each async.each in the last block as an input of the other async.each:

```
var results1 = {};
var results2 = {};
async.each(inputs, function (input, callback) {
    //Do something here and add some data to results1
    callback();
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        //Handeling error
    } else {
        async.each(results1, function (item, callback) {
            //Do something here and add some data to results2                      
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                //Handeling error
            } else {
                console.log("Final result", results2);
            }

        });
    }
});
```

or  **Example2:** where I have separate async.each blocks

```
var results1 = {};
async.each(inputs, function (input, callback) {
    //Do something here and add some data to results1
    callback();
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        //Handeling error
    }
});


var results2 = {};
async.each(results1, function (item, callback) {
    //Do something here and add some data to results2     
    callback();
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        //Handeling error
    } else {
        console.log("Final result", results2);
    }
});
```

**UPDATED:** 
Since the second approach is not right way and it is not guaranteed that the second async.each runs after the first one the problem is:  Does it mean I cannot have a simple for loop like the following example either? If yes, it is easy to change this one to async.each, but the problem is this one is recursive and that's make it complicated! If this needs to be async as well and not a for loop, do you know how I can have this recursive functionality here?

```
var results1 = {};
var results2 = [];
var results3 = {};
async.each(inputs, function (input, callback) {
    //Do something here and add some data to results1
    callback();
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        //Handeling error
    } else {

        // So in this case that I need to have nested function, does it mean I cannot have a simple for loop like this as well?
        //  If yes, it is easy to change this one to async.each, but the problem is this one is recursive and that's make it complicated! If this needs to be async as well, do you know how I can have this recursive functionality here?
        for (var input in inputs) {
            inferFromUnion(inputs[input], results1);
            results2.push(inputs[input]);
        }

        async.each(results2, function (item, callback) {
            //Do something here and add some data to results2                      
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                //Handeling error
            } else {
                console.log("Final result", results3);
            }

        });
    }
});


// Here just checking each object schema and if they are missing any fields from results1 we add that field with a value of null
function inferFromUnion(obj, allFields) {
    Object.keys(allFields).forEach(function (key) {
        if (lodash.isUndefined(obj[key])) {
            if (lodash.isPlainObject(allFields[key])) {
                obj[key] = {};
                inferFromUnion(obj[key], allFields[key]);
            } else {
                obj[key] = null;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example is the way to go, if you want to use results of the first bunch of calls in the second bunch. The second example won't work, because the second `async.each()` is guaranteed to run *before* the callbacks bound to your asynchronous operations.

---

Asynchronous recursion with loops is very much possible:

```
(function doSomeAsyncRecursion (results) {
    async.each(someItems, function (item, callback) {
        // ...
    }, function () {
        if (results /* ... (are incomplete) */) {
            doSomeAsyncRecursion(results);
        } else {
            // ... (results are complete now, do something with them)
        }
    });
})(/* initial value of results */);
```

Comment: Thaks so much man! So since the second approach is not right way and it is not guaranteed that the second async.each runs after the first one the problem is: Does it mean I cannot have a simple for loop like my new updated question? If yes, it is easy to change this one to async.each, but the problem is this one is recursive and that's make it complicated! If this needs to be async as well and not a for loop, do you know how I can have this recursive functionality here?

Comment: It is recommended to ask separate questions, not extend original question. That said, nothing stops you from having asynchronous recursion. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks man for your help; but still I'm struggeling with a solution for my problem; as recommended I opened my question in a new thread , in order not to mix many things http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533433/recursive-async-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded

Answer (score 1):

These two examples are different in desing. First example will run second async after first async is successful. But second example will run second async everytime, if theres an error or not.

Comment: So do you mean that in this case that I'm using results of one async.each as an input in another async.each, only the first example is right although I'm responding res.json(400,err) for error handeling?

Comment: Its tagged as NodeJS, which is async in nature. That means if first  call is waiting to process, second call will be called immediately, so result1 variable will be "undefined", because first one didnt responded with result in current loop.

Comment: Thaks so much man! So since the second approach is not right way and it is not guaranteed that the second async.each runs after the first one the problem is: Does it mean I cannot have a simple for loop like my new updated question? If yes, it is easy to change this one to async.each, but the problem is this one is recursive and that's make it complicated! If this needs to be async as well and not a for loop, do you know how I can have this recursive functionality here?

Comment: I really appreciate your help :-)